# Adding space between number and Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to add space between Numbers and Text in Excel.

Example:10AM to 10 AM,

Comment: What is your cell format? Is it text or time or number? You need to be more specific.

Comment: cell format is time.

Comment: Change the `NumberFormat` to `[$-en-US]h AM/PM;@` if you want to display the hours only. If you want the minutes too then you'd need `[$-en-US]h:mm AM/PM;@`.

Comment: @Ralph you should post this as an answer

Comment: @Peh Yes, of course, you are right. I just did and added a bit of an extra just to make it a real answer. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `NumberFormat` of the cell to

```
[$-en-US]h AM/PM;@
```

if you want to display the hours only. If you want the minutes too then you'd need

```
[$-en-US]h:mm AM/PM;@
```

For more options on how to format your dates / times you might want to read up here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Note, that all dates and times are (essentially) numbers which are merely formatted as dates and / or times.

The number `0.5` is half a day and equates to `12:00` noon. The number `0.25` is a quarter of a day and therefore `06:00 AM`. So, any fraction of a number is a fraction of a day.

At the same time all numbers before the decimal point are essentially the dates which are counted starting with the date `1899-12-31`. So, the number 1 is one day after the given date and therefore `1900-01-01`. And if you enter the number `42,801` into a cell and format it as a date then you get today's date because since `1899-12-31` more than 42 thousand days passed.

Comment: Why all the extra? `[$-en-US]` and `;@` ?

Comment: I am in a non-US country. If you live outside the US but want to enforce a US time layout then you should tell Excel. Otherwise, it can happen that the time format `AM/PM` is not recognized (my experience having working with more than 16 different Excel versions in different countries). The `;@` at the end is merely a [Character placeholder. Display a character or a space.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) for a bit of an indentation. But of course that's up to you and you can certainly skip that.

Answer (score 1):

Either change the number format to `h AM/PM` or:

```
=TEXT(A1,"h AM/PM")
```